# How to get result count from mysql inner join

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query something like this.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts . * , wp_geodir_gd_place_detail . * 
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_geodir_gd_place_detail ON ( wp_geodir_gd_place_detail.post_id = wp_posts.ID ) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
WHERE 1 =1
AND (
wp_posts.post_status =  'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status =  'private'
)
AND wp_posts.post_type =  'gd_place'
AND (
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
IN ( 2, 6, 8 )
)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC , wp_posts.post_title ASC
```

But its returning full rows with details. Can someone help me to get the count of affected rows instead of full rows?